# Обработка POSIX-сигналов: vsnprintf () и localtime_r() - безопасные функции?

Tags: linux, c, unix, posix, signal

Имеется в виду их использование в обработчике сигналов. Я знаю, что в списке безопасных функций из man signal для Linux RedHat их нет.

И все таки, какие есть мнения о возможности их вызывать, допустим обработчик не прерываем, тогда можно? Или можно, только для определенных участков прерываемого кода?

**Обновление**

Собственно сомнения в безопасности этих функций состоят 
в следующем:

`vsnprintf ()` - используется ли в `vsnprintf` пара `va_start()` ... `va_end()` и если да, то используют ли  `va_start()` ... `va_end()` неатомарные действия с нелокальными структурами данных?

Если на любой из этих вопросов ответ отрицательный, то `vsnprintf()` безопасна (в предположении, что она запрограммирована без `malloc()`).

`localtime_r ()` - откуда она берет timezone ?
Если не из файлов (а откуда ?), то безопасна.

Заранее благодарен за комментарии.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если нет уверенности, то лучше не рискуйте. Если есть возможность, то лучше делайте работу с "опасными" функциями в другом потоке, а обработчик сигналов пусть просто "пинает" этот поток и конфигурит необходимые параметры.

UPD:

Также посмотрите на следующее:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/916056/master-worker-threads-and-signal-handling

http://www.cognitus.net/html/howto/pthreadSemiFAQ_8.html

UPD 2: Ответ на дополнительные рассуждения автора вопроса

Слишком много предположений. Нельзя полагаться на такие вещи. Сегодня вы возможно "проскочите", но никто не гаратирует, что завтра кто-нибудь не "оптимизирует" vsnprintf и она вдруг не перестанет быть безопасной. Если спецификация не гарантирует её безопасность, то считаем её опасной. Любые догадки или даже раскопки её реализации ничего не гарантируют.